# unable to get token account balance from AccountInfo

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, rust, accountinfo

can anyone help me over here, please.

use solana_program::account_info::AccountInfo;

use spl_token::state::Account;

fn get_token_account_data(account_info: &AccountInfo) -> Result<Account, ProgramError> {
let account_data = account_info.data.borrow();
let account = Account::unpack(&account_data)?;
Ok(account)
}

let account = Account::unpack(&account_data);
|                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in spl_token::state::Account

Answer (score 2):

Both `pack` and `unpack` are provided by the `Pack` trait. You'll have to first bring the trait into scope with `use solana_program::program_pack::Pack;`