# Using HashMap in Solana Rust Contract

Tags: solana-program, rust

I have found that it is not possible to use HashMap, but BtreeStorage is possible. I have already tried to use those. But I  am getting errors.
I was trying to use this:
https://github.com/hashblock/solana-cli-program-template/blob/main/program/src/account_state.rs#L62
[image: Error found at building]

Comment: This issue might be unrelated to your use of Btrees. Does [this](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/6009/unable-to-get-token-account-balance-from-accountinfo/6013#6013) help?

Comment: @Ademola worked!!

Answer (score 1):

Both pack and unpack are provided by the Pack trait. You'll have to first bring the trait into scope with use solana_program::program_pack::Pack;